# For loop to create lists

Tags: r, list, for-loop, forecasting

Suppose you have the following dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(a=runif(n=348), b=runif(n=348), c=runif(n=348))
```

and then suppose that you would like to apply the `bld.mbb.bootstrap` function (from `forecast` package) for every column.

With one column the code will go like this:

```
reps <- 500L
sim <- bld.mbb.bootstrap(data$a, reps)
```

Which returns a list of 500.

Question 1: How do I get to change all the names? To say iteration #i (inside the list).

Question 2: I want to make a for loop that does "sim" for all the columns in the dataframe. So I think it'd go like this:

```
for (i in names(data)){

sim <- bld.mbb.bootstrap(data$i, reps)

}
```

How can I make a list that stores (in this case 3) lists?

I want a list that contains 3 lists named like the variable: a, b, and c.

where a, b, c are lists that contain the iterations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might suffice `lapply(colnames(data), function(x) bld.mbb.bootstrap(data[,x], reps))`

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, any tip on how to change the names of the "sublists"?

Comment: You can use `names(result) <- c("a", "b", etc..)` or take a look at `?setNames`

Comment: `names(sim) <- names(data)` will do the trick! Thanks!! Can you post this answer to mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **base R** approach using `lapply`

```
lapply(data, function(x) bld.mbb.bootstrap(x, reps))
```

or

```
setNames(lapply(colnames(data), function(x) 
  bld.mbb.bootstrap(data[,x], reps)), colnames(data))
```